# Error setting up new React project when moving index.html to public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have been struggling with a seemingly simple issue. I was working on setting up a new React Project and structuring my folder. I had something like this:

```
/node_modules
/public
   |__ 0.bundle.js
   |__ bundle.js
   // the goal is to move index.html in this folder
/src
   |__components
   App.js
   ClientApp.js
.babelrc
.eslintrc
index.html
package.json
server.js
webpack.config.js
yarn.lock
```

Now my index file looks simply like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"><%= body %></div>
  <script src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my server.js is:

```
require('babel-register')

const express = require('express')
const React = require('react')
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
const ReactRouter = require('react-router-dom')
const StaticRouter = ReactRouter.StaticRouter
const _ = require('lodash')
const fs = require('fs')
const PORT = 5000
const baseTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./index.html')
const template = _.template(baseTemplate)
const App = require('./src/App').default

const server = express()

server.use('/public', express.static('./public'))

server.use((req, res) => {
  const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    React.createElement(StaticRouter, {location: req.url, context: {}},
      React.createElement(App)
    )
  )

  res.write(template({body: body}))
  res.end()
})

console.log('listening on port', PORT)
server.listen(PORT)
```

And everything works like a charm (both server and client rendering), now I wanted to make a simple change and move the `index.html` file inside the `/public` folder. I did it updating the respective files that were pointing to it as well as where `index` is looking for the `bundle.js.` file. So my new `index.html` is:

```
...
<body>
  <div id="app"><%= body %></div>
  <!-- <script src="/public/bundle.js"></script> I actually removed this -->
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

And my server is updated to:

```
...
const baseTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./public/index.html')
const template = _.template(baseTemplate)
const App = require('./src/App').default

...
server.listen(PORT)
```

With this setup client rendering still works but server side rendering throws an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

It took me a while to pinpoint the issue. and apparently the `server.js` is capable of detecting the file after I move it to the `public` folder (if I inspect the `HTML` it is in fact there), but it has troubles loading the actual app (meaning the js). I feel like making this change broke some references that I am now giving for granted. Any thought on where to look for my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny enough I found out what the problem was, my configuration had issues that involved `webpack` as well, that I was skipping over. I did not update the `output` path according to my new configuration.

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  // publicPath: '/public/' --> This was causing the error
  publicPath: '/js/'
},
```

The reason why that was causing the error is due to the fact that if `index.html` is placed in the main folder (as it was originally) then it needs to look for the bundles inside the `public` folder as the old `webpack` config specified with `publicPath`. After moving the `index.html` inside the `public` folder, the bundles would now be in the same folder as the `index.html` file so the path we should refer to is now `index` own folder. This translates into the new `publicPath` specified in the snippet above.

I hope this can help others, I should have been more aware of my `webpack` config and I would have not ran into this issue. Happy coding!